# Textarea hides enter if it is the first character from post

Tags: html, post, textarea, line-breaks, enter

I have a question.
When I post my textarea and I retrieve it with $_POST from PHP and the text starts with an "enter" it is left out.
So when I enter two "enters" in the textarea and I post it, the next time it shows only one "enter" in the textarea. When I post it again, there are no "enters" left in the textarea.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about preserving line breaks? if yes, than you need `nl2br()`

Comment: No, I just have this `<textarea><?=$_POST['textarea']?></textarea>` and this shows something different than what my input was if it starts with a line break

Comment: What happens to the POST data, is it processed in any way? How do you check the content? Please post some code to show what you have done so far.

Comment: Well in short it is this:
`<textarea name='textarea'><?=$_POST['textarea']?></textarea>` with a submit button.
But it shows the content I entered without the first line break

Comment: Check it here:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wb1-cjv
Click on run, enter for example 3 "enters" click save and then there are 2 "enters" in the textarea....

Comment: I fixed it with javascript/jQuery:

Javascript:
`document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = '<?=str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "\\n", $_POST['textarea']);?>';`

jQuery:
`$("#textarea").html('<?=str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "\\n", $_POST['textarea']);?>');`

This does the trick for me. It is just replacing all line-breaks with "\n" and puts this in the textarea. If you don't do this, the first line-break will be left out and now it won't.

Comment: Won't that interfere with the user typing "\n" in the text?